# Excel - Rather complex SUM IF criteria

Tags: excel

I have roughly the following setup:

Values:

```
MONTH | DURATION | VALUE | 
  5   |     3    |  120  |
  6   |     1    |  100  |
```

**Expected** outcome for totals:

```
MONTH | TOTAL
  5   |  120
  6   |  220
  7   |  120
```

What I would like to do, is to be able to sum in another table the total values for each month. The logic would be to SUM every value where the total table's month is equal or higher than that of the values, but lower than the value's month + duration.

Does that make any sense? Is that possible? I'm cracking my head and I can't seem to find a way to solve it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: An example where a) the expected outcome matches the input and b) gives some explanation of how the summing applies to the specific example, would be helpful.  For example, shouldn't month=7 be in the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DSUM` is the best candidate for this, I believe.  See [Microsft's documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DSUM-function-53181285-0c4b-4f5a-aaa3-529a322be41b?NS=EXCEL&Version=16&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZXL160&HelpId=xlmain11.chm60089&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) and [this site](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Dsum-Function.html) for help understanding function, and what it is doing.  I have made very complex calculations possible in Excel by using the "database" methods (`DSUM`, `DCOUNT`, etc).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is probably to make another column with the end month. And then use SUMIFS to check if month is >= starting month and <= ending month.

```
=SUMIFS(<Range of Values>,<Range of starting>,"<="& "Target month",<Range of ending>,">="& <Target month>)
```